# My Posts are automatically deleted in gce_discussions group

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-groups

Tagging google_compute_engine in this post incase other users are having problems posting to that particular google group

For the last few days I've been trying to post to the gce_discussions google group but my posts don't turn up even days afterwards and the email subscription thats created are listed as no longer accessible.

If I reply to a post in gce_discussions it gets listed as deleted almost immediately.
I've tried different browsers and cleared caches 
I've un-subscribed and re-subscribed to the forum again but that doesn't solve it.
I have in the past been able to post topics to the group using the web browser

I can post to other google groups and if I use the email address for the gce-discussion forum I can post using the email address for the gce_discussion forum 
I have a screen shot of the email subscriptions but I don't have the necesssary rep to include here at the moment

Has anyone else had problems posting to the forum?
How do you get support for google groups outside of google groups?

Comment: You should probably contact one of the list administrators or project owners.

Comment: Thanks, any ideas where you find those details? Only links I could find were to report abuse

Comment: as mentioned in the 1st line I tagged it google-compute-engine in case others were having similar trouble with that particular forum or in case the group admins happen to see it